# "Reset" object to default values; recall constructor?

Tags: c++, object, constructor

I have a class `characterData` with a constructor:

```
class characterData() {
    private:
        int position[2];
        vector<vector<int> > pixelData;
        int num;
    public:
        characterData() {
            num = -1;
        }
        void setValues(int p[2], vector<vector<int> > v, int n) {
            position[0] = p[0];
            position[1] = p[1];
            pixelData = v;
            num = n; // if setValues() is called, n will always > -1
        }
};
```

I do it this way so I can have an "empty" `characterData` in my code. My thought process is if `num == -1`, `setValues()` has not been called on the `characterData` object.

Later in my code I have a `characterData k` which is only initialized, `setValues()` has not been called upon it, so `k.num == -1`.

Eventually I change the value of `k` but wish to "reset" it to its original form.

```
characterData k;
// some assignments happen, k = something else
k = new characterData(); // reset k
```

The above doesn't work. I need to reset `k` such that `k.num == -1`. There is no member setter/mutator function that can allow me to change `num` at all: my thought was to recall constructor but this doesn't work.

How do I reset `k` to an "empty" state?

Comment: what if they call `setValues` with `n == -1` ?

Comment: @M.M `n` is derived from the size of a `list`. `n` is never below 0 as stated in the question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just use the default constructor again:

```
  characterData c;
  c.setvalues( ... );
  c = characterData();
```

Although I wouldn't say this is a particularly great design.

Comment: I agree it isn't good design, but I'm creating a backbone on which to improve. I need a way to create an "empty" `characterData` as well as reset something to an empty `characterData`.

Comment: Why is this a bad design / do you have an improvement in mind?

Comment: This seems like a great design. It puts all of the logic in one place. I guess one other alternative is to have an "Init" function which is called by constructor and can be called elsewhere.

Answer (score 4):

Add a `clear` function maybe?

```
    void clear() {
        num = -1;
    }
```